# Converting time in milliseconds since epoch to time in yy-dd-hh-ss format

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have a bunch of tasks which are in the order of microseconds, the below code prints only until seconds (Thu Oct 21 12:48:20 2021) so comparing the values of start and finish always ends up giving 0. I want to be able to compare in the order of milliseconds and microseconds. Is there a function to help with this?

Also, is there a way to convert `uint64_t current1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();` to `time_t` to print out the current time based on the `count()`?

```
const auto p1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(p1);
    std::cout << "now: " << std::ctime(&now);
```

Comment: At least in most implementations, `time_t` has a resolution of one second.

Comment: Look into https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono there are plenty of standard facilities that handle subsecond time intervals (but `time_t` is not one of them, consider using something else).

Comment: If you are comparing "start" and "finish" times, you should be using `std::chrono::steady_clock`.  `system_clock` can not be relied on for timing because, like wall clocks, they can abruptly jump forward and backward.

Comment: Okay, and is there a way to convert to print std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() in readable format of date-time ?

Comment: Just did. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I recommend skipping the C timing API entirely.  It is error-prone and doesn't handle sub-second precision.

If UTC (as opposed to local time) is ok, then there is a [header-only, open-source preview of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that works with C++11/14/17:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    const auto p1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "now: " << p1 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
now: 2021-10-21 20:28:15.754423
```

To port the above program to C++20 (which is already shipping in the latest Visual Studio), just drop the `#include "date/date.h"` and `using date::operator<<;`.

If you need *local* time, that can be also be had in C++20 (shipping in VS), but the [open-source preview of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) is no longer header only.  There exists one source file that needs to be compiled, and depending on your needs, might require a download of the IANA tz database.

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    const auto p1 = system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "now: " << zoned_time{current_zone(), p1} << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
now: 2021-10-21 16:28:15.754423 EDT
```

The above syntax assumes C++17.  For C++11/14 the template parameter for `zoned_time` needs to be specified:  `zoned_time<system_clock::duration>`.

The above program ports to C++20 by dropping `#include "date/tz.h"` and `using namespace date;`.

In either program you can truncate to millisecond precision with:

```
const auto p1 = floor<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
```

Answer (score 1):

`time_t` is usually an integer specifying (whole) seconds.

You could get the millseconds by subtracting the whole-second `time_t` from `now`:

```
auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
              p1 - std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(now)).count();
```

or using `operator%`:

```
auto ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>p1)
             .time_since_epoch() % std::chrono::seconds(1);

std::cout << ms.count();
```

Example how you could do the formatting:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using Precision = std::chrono::milliseconds;

    auto time_point = Clock::now();

    // extract std::time_t from time_point
    std::time_t t = Clock::to_time_t(time_point);

    // output the part supported by std::tm
    std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%FT%T."); // select format here

    // get duration since epoch
    auto dur = time_point.time_since_epoch();

    // extract the sub second part from the duration since epoch
    auto ss =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<Precision>(dur) % std::chrono::seconds{1};

    // output the millisecond part
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << ss.count();
}
```

Comment: this is printing epoch time Wed Dec 31 16:05:07 1969. How do I get the current time in millisecond

Comment: @learnzz You need to print the `ms` part separately. There is no standard function to do it afaik. The `ms` variable in my answer holds _only_ the remaining milliseconds. from `p1`

Comment: Also, do you know how to seconds since epoch to current time(Readable) uint64_t current1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

Comment: @learnzz `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(seconds_since_epoch)` should work.

Comment: what type of variable should this be stored as ? std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(seconds_since_epoch)

Comment: @learnzzI always use `auto` but it's a `time_point<system_clock>` (in your case)

Comment: My time has std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count(); - the count in specific and not just the time_since_epoch(). I believe this counts are the number of seconds this epoch

Comment: I am unable to run cout << d , where auto d= std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(current1); The error I am seeing is "no operator matches these operands << "

Comment: @learnzz `time_since_epoch` returns the _duration_ for `system_clock` it's most likely not seconds but something with higher precision. Did you try the example I added to the answer?

Comment: uint64_t current1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
 std::chrono::system_clock::time_point de = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(current1);
 cout << de;

Comment: `time_since_epoch` does not return a `time_t` so you shouldn't use `from_time_t` on it directly. Try staying within the `chrono` domain as long as possible and only convert to raw integers when you need to present something that isn't supported by the streaming operators directly (yet).

Also, take a look at HowardHinnants date library that he links to in the other answer. It's brilliant.